# Rails test sending emails for real

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't know why but my tests are sending emails for real.

This is my `config/environments/test.rb`:

```
# Send emails
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false

# Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
# The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
# ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

It's basically the default test config for Rails.
For quite some time I have been writing code like this:

```
if !Rails.env.test?
  mail(:to=>to, :subject=>"#{group_name} - #{subject}")
end
```

But I really want to know why **config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false** and **config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test** are not working.

Any clue?

Comment: Are your tests running in the wrong environment for some reason? Try asserting `Rails.env.test?` to be sure it's correct.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, but just for sanity, I wrote  pp Rails.env.test? right before sending an email. It's printing true.

Comment: That should be `config/environments/test.rb` but otherwise it looks like it's configured correctly. Is that code within a notifier-type ActionMailer derived class?

Comment: Yes, ActionMailer::Base < ApplicationMailer < MessageMailer.

Comment: Double-inheriting?

Comment: No, MessageMailer < AplicationMailer and ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I still don't see anything obviously wrong here. Maybe something else is turning off test mode before it has a chance to send. If this is a recent regression, maybe checking earlier versions if you're using version control could shed some light on the issue.

Comment: Try to break it down by creating a reproducible example - this is not the intended behavior and either you have something strange going on in your config or you have found a legitimate bug.

Comment: Yes, I will try to create a new project from the scratch. See if this option is working at all. By the way, I'm using Rails 5.0.0.1

Comment: @raonirenosto did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: @TKAB Yes, some problem with my aws ses config, after a while I figured out that  the configuration was overriding variables for environments. My mistake, but at the time was really difficult to track down the error.